# swift - dismissing view controller from UIAlertController action prevents view controller from deiniting

Tags: swift

on a press of the close button I'm running this code

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey!", message: "What to do?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { [weak self]_ in

            self?.alert.dismiss(animated: true)

        })

        let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {[weak self] _ in

             self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        })

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(closeAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

If the user presses on the close action, the view controller (self) will not deinit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to keep a reference of the UIAlertContorller on the view controller and nullify it before closing the view controller.

```
self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey!", message: "What to do?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
```

and

```
let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {[weak self] _ in

    self?.alert = nil
    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

})
```

Comment: you can try using weak var for your alert controller.

Comment: If I'm doing that, the alert sometimes remains nil `weak var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey!", message: "What to do?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet); if let alert = alert {

            print("alert") }` - The alert most of the times doesn't get called.